# Как обратиться к функции?

Tags: print, массивы, php

Есть функция, которая возвращает массив. Как можно обратиться к ее элементам? Например:

```
function get_array(){
...
return $arr;
}
```

Если попробовать `echo get_array()[0];`, то `PHP` выдаст ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a = get_array();
$a[0];
```

Php - это вам не javascript. =)

П.С. А в javascript'е - `get_array()[0];` .

Comment: Тау я уже делал :-). Напрямую значит нельзя обратиться?

Comment: Увы, никак.

Answer (score 2):

А если применить такой костыль :)))

```
class A{
        public $data=array();
        function __construct($data){
             $this->data=$data;
        }
}
function returnArray($data){
     $a=new A($data);
     return $a;
}
print_r(returnArray(array('msg'=>'Hello World'))->data['msg']);
```